# Caching proxy with node.js

Tags: node.js, proxy

Are there any solutions for creating caching http proxy server on node.js ?

Comment: i am using server linux debian ...

Answer (score 0):

you dont specify what is the reason you want to create proxy in node.js.This is simple tutorial about proxy in [node.js](http://thechangelog.com/post/872114581/node-http-proxy-reverse-proxy-for-node-js).list of proxy available under this [node.js](http://toolbox.no.de/categories/Proxy).Here sample [code](https://github.com/d11wtq/node-http-cache).